# Proving for all elements of a list in coq

Tags: coq

How can I prove that H and my goal are same for all elements of the list?

```
X : Type
P : X -> Prop
l : list X
H : forall n : X, ~ (In n l /\ ~ P n)
______________________________________(1/1)
forall b : X, In b l -> P b
```

The two statements `~ (In n l /\ ~ P n)` and `In b l -> P b` are equal. I tried `apply imply_to_or` on the goal to simplify but couldn't unify.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure this is constructively true?

Comment: It'd be better if you provided your imports and the actual statement what of you are trying to prove ([mcve]). (1) It'll save us some typing. (2) It'll tell us you are working within the realm of classical logic. Also, I guess whatever you are proving about lists can be proved with constructive logic. (I mean on a broad scale, not this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we need some imports:

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
```

We reason "backwards" when applying lemmas to the goal.
This means you need a lemma that has implication as its consequent, *not* premiss.

We can `Search (~ ?p \/ ?c -> ?p -> ?c).` for it and this will get you:

```
or_to_imply: forall P Q : Prop, ~ P \/ Q -> P -> Q
```

The above lemma will work, but we can do a little bit better: we can make use of the `tauto` tactic, and voilà, you have a simple proof:

```
Goal forall (X : Type) (P : X -> Prop) (l : list X),
       (forall n, ~ (In n l /\ ~ P n)) ->
       forall b, In b l -> P b.
  intros X P l H b.
  specialize H with b.
  tauto.
Qed.
```